# Using async and tasks in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to create a method that look like this

```
protected override Task
        HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
            OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement,
            string resource)
    {
        if (context.User == null || resource == null)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        var members = await TeamsGraph.GetTeamMembers(resource, context.User);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

This method gives me an error because I have the await TeamsGraph, which requires the method to marked as async.  If I add async to the method then the 2 lines that say Task.FromResults(0) are then in error.  The return of that specific type is required by the underlying method that I'm overriding.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I just haven't done a ton with the Async Await, so I'm looking for guidance on how to setup this method.

**Edit**

Let's see if I can cover everybody's comments below.

**rmjoia** - If I add async in front of Task then the 2 return Task.FromResult(0) lines are in error.

**Bradley Uffner** - The code that I'm doing is from the Authorization examples from ASP.NET Core and it is what is expected to be returned.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data for an example.

**David**  - There is more to the code after the await line to check that the user is a TeamMember, I just ommitted that for simplicity sack.

**JSteward** - Since you were the first one who suggested this can you submit an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: add async before task, you're done, yes as @JSteward said, remove the Task.FromResult(0);

Comment: Mark the method `async` and simply remove `Task.FromResult`, when a method is marked `async` and returns only `Task` you do not need a `return` statement.

Comment: What type of value are you returning?  Your method is declared as `Task`, which doesn't return any value, but you are using `Task.FromResult(0)` to try and return `0`.  If you need to return an `int`, it should be `Task<int>`.  You need to pick one or the other.

Comment: @BradleyUffner That will fail for the exact same reason

Comment: @Servy What do you mean?  Trying to return `Task.FromResult(0)` from a method declared as `Task` seems like an obvsious mistake.  One of those needs to change, what am I missing?

Comment: It's not clear what this method even *should* be returning or doing.  You're trying to return hard-coded integer values, and the only async operation inside the method is resulting in a completely ignored result.  You could just replace the entire body of the method with `return Task.FromResult(0);`  Can you clarify the actual intent here?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Returning `Task.FromReslut(0)` in a method that returns a `Task` works just fine.  Returning `0` in an async method that returns a `Task` does not.

Comment: @Servy I never suggested trying to directly return `0`.  I'm just saying that either the method signature is wrong, or the `return` statement is wrong when combined with the `async` they originally had, but removed.

Comment: Assuming that the signature of the method you are overriding is correctly returning `Task`, I would add the `async` back, and completely remove any return statement. But that will make the code content you have in there meaningless, so you should probably rethink what you are actually trying to do there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning `Task<int>` not just `Task`

```
protected override async Task<int> HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        OperationAuthorizationRequirement requirement,
        string resource)
{
    if (context.User == null || resource == null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    var members = await TeamsGraph.GetTeamMembersAsync(resource, context.User);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No because I'm overriding a method that is not possible

Comment: Then you cannot return async 0 or Task.FromResult(0), that's the equivalent of trying to do return 0 in a void method.

Answer (score 0):

are you able to do this:

```
  var members = TeamsGraph.GetTeamMembers(resource, context.User);
  members.Wait();
```